# using a dbt source with references to multiple

Tags: yaml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

I have a datawarehouse that ingests data from multiple databases, these sit in the same database in my warehouse but logically split into different schemas.

Now if i have the following model.

```sql
#my_cool_model.sql
SELECT a.ID, b.DATE
FROM {{ source(var('environment'), 'table_a') }} a 
INNER JOIN {{ source((var('environment'), 'table_b') }} b
```

---

and a `sources.yaml` that refers to my databases sources.

```
#sources.yaml
version: 2

sources:

  - name: staging
    database: staging
    schema: sales
    tables:
     - name: table_a


   # what I've tried.
    schema: finance
    tables:
      - name: table_b
```

this is a simple abstraction but it illustrates my point.

when I try to compile or run my model

```bash
dbt compile -m my_cool_model --vars "{'environment' : 'staging'}"
```

I'll get an error that states that this model relies on a model where `table_a` does not exist which I assume means that my `table_a` references is being over-written.

before I go down the path of refactoring how my data is stored in the warehouse is there a nice work around or is this a limitation of dbt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are two different schemas, they should be treated as two different sources. The `source_name` you pass into `source()` should not be driving the environment. You can do that by either using Jinja within the yml or by overriding `source()` with your own macro (which I wouldn't recommend in this case).

Example:

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: sales
    database: "{{ env_var('environment') }}"
    schema: sales # Not needed since it matches the source name
    tables:
      - name: table_a

  - name: finance
    database: "{{ env_var('environment') }}"
    schema: finance
    tables:
      - name: table_b
```

```
#my_cool_model.sql
SELECT a.ID, b.DATE
FROM {{ source('sales', 'table_a') }} a 
INNER JOIN {{ source('finance', 'table_b') }} b
```

Also, just one comment on best practices: I would recommend splitting the sources into their own ymls and creating base models for each, then `ref()` those models in `my_cool_model.sql`. Your base models should know the specific configurations of where sources come from, then your downstream models don't need to worry about it.

EDIT to elaborate on "best practices": It's a best practice because you don't want your transformation stage models to have to know about where the data originated from. It just needs to know it has the data available to it. DBT provides their own recommendations [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/best-practices/how-we-structure/1-guide-overview#guide-structure-overview). Personally, I do things a little different:

1. Base models: Only knows about sources. One model, one source. Provides simple data type conversions, establishes field name conventions, interprets enum values, etc. No transformations or joins with other sources/models.
2. Clean models: Removes garbage data from your base models. Possible simple data enrichment.
3. Staging (or intermediate) models: Transformations.
4. Mart: Final destination. Facts and dimension tables.

Comment: This is interesting, in terms of best practice why would you create models for data sources that are ingested and controlled outside of dbt?

Comment: and also works really well, now I'm kicking my self for not thinking of this earlier! the reason it might not work is because I have a legacy source that's all in one database, but I think I can make this work thanks mate!

Comment: @Umar.H - Updated answer to address your question about "best practices". Of course, best practices can be slightly opinionated, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: awesome thanks mate! This didn't 100% work for me because my microservices name schemas differently by environments (sad face) but I was able to extract each "source" at a level with a "name_env" which I can then call via `vars` Thanks for the tips mate really appreciate it!